# Adding functionality using pointers to reset values inside an array

Tags: c#, pointers, memory-management, .net-core, reference

I'm writing a program that allows the re-usage of memory of an already defined array. The array is initialized with initial data, which can be modified. After we've decided that we need to re-use the memory, the idea is to revert back the array to its initial original values. The idea I had in mind is to use pointers that point to every element in the array, so that when needed, to revert them back to their previous value. For some reason though, it doesn't accomplish this.

```
public struct MemoryOptimizer
    {
        public static MemoryBlock[] memoryBlocks = new MemoryBlock[10000];
        public static int counter = 0;

        public static void ResetToOriginalValues()
        {
            memoryBlocks.AsParallel().ForAll((element) =>
            {
                if (element != null)
                    element.Revert();
            });
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {

        public static unsafe int* MemoryParse(this string s)
        {
            int parsedValue = Int32.Parse(s);
            int* ptr = &parsedValue;
            MemoryOptimizer.memoryBlocks[MemoryOptimizer.counter++] = new MemoryBlock()
            {
                pointerToCurrentValue = ptr,
                fallbackValue = *ptr
            };
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    public unsafe class MemoryBlock
    {
        public int* pointerToCurrentValue;
        public int fallbackValue;

        public void Revert()
        {
            unsafe
            {
                *pointerToCurrentValue = fallbackValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = "1";
    string b = "2", c = "3", d = "4";

    unsafe
    {
        int* ga = b.MemoryParse();
        *ga = 449494;
        int*[] array = new int*[] { a.MemoryParse(), b.MemoryParse(), c.MemoryParse(), d.MemoryParse() };
        foreach (int* asd in array)
        {
            Console.Write(*asd + ",");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        *array[0] = 123;
        *array[1] = 444;
        *array[2] = 4151;
        *array[3] = 1895;
        foreach (int* asd in array)
        {
            Console.Write(*asd + ",");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        MemoryOptimizer.ResetToOriginalValues();
        foreach (int* asd in array)
        {
            Console.Write(*asd + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Not only are the values incorrect in the array, but it seems after I'm debugging that all the pointers point to the same address, when populating the array. The address for `ga` variable is okay, and if I manipulate it, it works, and resetting it to its original value with `MemoryOptimizer.ResetToOriginalValues()` also works.

All of that for the `array` though, does not work.

**EDIT:** If we remove the array altogether, and declare another `int` using the extension method, it ruins the pointer for the previous one. Seems it only works, if we ever use the method once, which basically means nothing works.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you're doing this? Is it an academic exercise? I'm just not sure why anyone would choose to do this in modern C#, which is memory managed and when memory is no longer at a premium like it was in older times.

Comment: @robbpriestley I've never used the unsafe keyword, or pointers in C# before. If I used C++ I'd have already solved this in various ways. You're correct. It's just an exercise so I can better understand how these things work in C# and what rocks you can stumble upon when using them.

Comment: Yes, OK it's an interesting exercise but ultimately unnecessary. C# is memory managed and has a garbage collector do you don't need to worry about re-using memory or deallocating. Just re-assign your variables instead of re-mapping memory, etc. Of course we usually prefer to be as efficient as possible with our memory usage, but in most modern cases unless you are deploying to embedded systems it is not a big concern.